# Issue with Google Charts API while paging table

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Using [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/) with a code like this:

```
<div id='table_div'></div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
function drawTable() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
  data.addColumn('number', 'A');
  data.addColumn('number', 'B');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Total');
  data.addRows([
      ['United States',     19, 115, 134],
      ['United Kingdom',     3,  23,  26],
      ['Germany',            2,  19,  21],
      ['Ireland',            0,   3,   3],
      ['Belgium',            2,   3,   5],
      ['Russian Federation', 0,   2,   2],
        ...
  ]);

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
  table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, page: 'enable', pageSize: '10', sortColumn: 3, sortAscending: false});
}
</script>
```

It causes a weird issue while paging. Having 38 counties, each page shows:

- #1 - 10 countries (from 1 to 10)
- #2 - 28 countries (from 11 to 38)
- #3 - 18 countries. Somehow, although the second page already listed the rest of the countries, there is a third page that lists countries from 21 to 38, again
- #4 - 8 countries (from 31 to 38), that were already listed

**JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/HT3St/

I tested the code also on [Code Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#table) and the same issue happened. Is this some known bug that I don't know?

Comment: if you use `arrayToDataTable` instead of `DataTable`, is the same bug appearing?

Comment: Yes, the same bug happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I've found how to resolve this, I enforce the option again and it resolves the bug:

```
 var options = {
   alternatingRowStyle:[true],
   pageSize:[20],
   page:['enable']
    };

  options['pageSize'] = 20; <- This line fix the problem.
```

Try it :)

Answer (score 3):

```
{showRowNumber: true, 
 page: 'enable', 
 pageSize: '10', 
 sortColumn: 3, 
 sortAscending: false
}
```

Your pageSize was set to a string. Note the quotes around the 10. It has to be a number like so

```
pageSize: 10,
```