# Google API java client - pageSize

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

Why does `service.list().setPageSize(pageSize)` not work? It does not return list of elements with specified `pageSize`. Where is the problem?

**EDIT**

Here is example of code that **does not work**:

```
Appsactivity.Activities.List request = service.activities().list()
        .setDriveFileId(fileId)
        .setGroupingStrategy("driveUi")
        .setSource("drive.google.com")
        .setUserId("me")
        .setPageSize(pageSize);

ListActivitiesResponse response = request.execute();

do {
   response = request.execute();
   List<Activity> items = response.getActivities();        
   System.out.println(items.size());
   request.setPageToken(response.getNextPageToken());

} while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
```

If I have 7 activities and `pageSize = 3` than it does not return pages 3, 3, 1 as expected, but instead of it returns pages of size 6, 1.

The same problem is discussed here [Issue with Google Charts API while paging table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993441/issue-with-google-charts-api-while-paging-table) but setting pageSize directly via `.set("pageSize", pageSize)` and `.set("page", "enable")` did not help.

Another question like this [app-engine-java-api-pagesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846688/app-engine-java-api-pagesize)

Comment: If you want more help you should say which API you're using, which method and share the complete code. What value do you use for pageSize ? What is the issue ? Does it return a list with a different number of elements or does it return something else/nothing ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It happens when I work with **Google Apps Activity API** but I think the same applies for other services (see my post edit).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as I am new to Google API. I have used it with Python. I think you need to append the command with `.execute()` and use `service.list().setPageSize(pageSize).execute()` . Here is the link to the source code for the [script](https://github.com/lakshayg/dotfiles/blob/master/conky/.conky/gmail.py) I wrote using Gmail API.